# Displaying densely curved vectors at smaller scales

Tags: qgis, cartography

Some time ago I came across a QGIS cartographic technique that solved a problem that occurs when detailed vector data is displayed at smaller scales: densely-curving lines become smudged and look darker than the surrounding straight lines.  Sinuous rivers and coastlines are common problem areas.

Here's a screenshot that shows some highlighted example areas.  The following screenshot shows the detail from the red rectangle.

[image]

[image]

The technique that I vaguely recall solves this problem *without* running a generalizing tool, so that the curvy sections display with the same darkness (density? detail?) as straight lines.  I've searched the QGIS docs and the internet without success.

The **Cartographic Line Generalization** plugin looked promising (even though it is a tool, which I thought the solution did not require), but its input window does not display properly on my 4K screen.  I've tried using it as best I can read it, but all results have errors that I can't relate to the plugin window.  Unfortunately, the plugin home page has no instructions.

[image]

Did I really see this technique, or am I dreaming?

Comment: You may try to get the geometry generator to output simplified line

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360683/88814 or try `simplify()` function with geometry generator (this does not affect the geometry, it's just for visualization).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the rendering simplification in the layer settings. Play around with the algorithm and threshold until you find something that works for you:

[image]

[image]